# Not founding libraries in project panama on macOs

Tags: java, project-panama

I am trying to run cpp code via Java using the Project Panama and I got an error because my library is not loading.

cpp code:

```
// MyRectangle.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    Rectangle(int, int);
    int area() {return width*height;}
};

Rectangle::Rectangle(int w, int h) {
  this->width = w;
  this->height = h;
}

// Expose C ABI for Panama to call into.
extern "C" int rectArea(int, int);
int rectArea(int w, int h) {
    std::cout << "Inside C++ Code " << std::endl;
    Rectangle rect(w,h);
    return rect.area();
}
```

I compile by this:
g++ -dynamiclib -current_version 1.0  -o libmyrectangle.dylib MyRectangle.cpp

and Java code:

```
class MyRectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.loadLibrary("myrectangle");


        var cLinker = CLinker.systemCLinker();


// C function int rectArea(int w, int h)
        MethodHandle rectAreaMH = cLinker.downcallHandle(cLinker.lookup("rectArea").get(),
                FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.OfInt.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.OfInt.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.OfInt.JAVA_INT));

// Return area of rectangle
        int w = 8;
        int h = 2;
        int area = (int) rectAreaMH.invokeExact(w, h);

        System.out.printf("MethodHandle calling rectArea(%d, %d) = (%d)\n", w, h, area);
    }
}
```

and I got error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no myrectangle in java.library.path: ~/Users/project-panama-examples

It seems that java doesn't see my library, but why? Is it a bug?

Comment: `-Djava.library.path=directory-where-your-library-is`

Comment: I got it and still the same :/

Comment: What command did you use to run?

Comment: java -cp target/classes/ 
    --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED 
    --add-modules jdk.incubator.foreign -Djava.library.path= ~ /Users/project-panama-examples
    com.example. MyRectangle.java

Comment: Are you sure that library path is correct? It looks like you're missing the user directory (unless your user is `project-panama-expamples`). You could also try `System.load(<absolute path>)`.

Comment: The same issue when I indicate directly path to library

Comment: *-Djava.library.path= ~ /Users/project-panama-examples* There's at least one space in that. Should be `-Djava.library.path=~/Users/project-panama-examples`
PLUS: do you *really* have a directory called 'Users' right off your *home* directory? And are you running on a Unix flavour?

Comment: The path is changed for this post, but problem is that macOS don't recognize this library. On Linux is works but C function is not found  ;/

Comment: Do you think that C++ code is correct? I compiled cpp code : g++ -shared -o MyRectangle.so MyRectangle.cpp and Java doesn't recognize rectArea function. Maybe on mac is a problem because this code is not valid..

Answer (score 1):

Panama is not compatible yet with `arm64`, that is M1 MacBooks. I'm assuming yours is one of those?

You can still run your code inside a docker container with x86_64 architecture. For my own experiments I put together this [dockerfile](https://github.com/dili91/rust-java-interop/blob/main/Dockerfile).